# Value not getting from Kafka topic using Java Spark - kafka direct stream

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, kafka-consumer-api

I am not getting any data from  the queue using Kafka direct stream. In my code I put System.out.println() This statement not run that means I am not getting any data from that topic..

I am pretty sure data available in queue and since not getting in console.

I didn't see any error in console also.

Can anyone please suggest something?

Here is my Java code,

```
SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("JavaKafkaWordCount11").setMaster("local[*]");
        sparkConf.set("spark.streaming.concurrentJobs", "3");

        // Create the context with 2 seconds batch size
        JavaStreamingContext jssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sparkConf, new Duration(3000));

        Map<String, Object> kafkaParams = new HashMap<>();
        kafkaParams.put("bootstrap.servers", "x.xx.xxx.xxx:9092");
        kafkaParams.put("key.deserializer", StringDeserializer.class);
        kafkaParams.put("value.deserializer", StringDeserializer.class);
        kafkaParams.put("group.id", "use_a_separate_group_id_for_each_stream");
        kafkaParams.put("auto.offset.reset", "latest");
        kafkaParams.put("enable.auto.commit", true);

        Collection<String> topics = Arrays.asList("topicName");

        final JavaInputDStream<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(jssc,
                LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent(),
                ConsumerStrategies.<String, String>Subscribe(topics, kafkaParams));


        JavaPairDStream<String, String> lines = stream
                .mapToPair(new PairFunction<ConsumerRecord<String, String>, String, String>() {
                    @Override
                    public Tuple2<String, String> call(ConsumerRecord<String, String> record) {

                        return new Tuple2<>(record.key(), record.value());
                    }
                });

        lines.print();

        // System.out.println(lines.count());
        lines.foreachRDD(rdd -> {
            rdd.values().foreachPartition(p -> {
                while (p.hasNext()) {
                    System.out.println("Value of Kafka queue" + p.next());
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: Two ideas to check: 1) does new data flow into your topic? By default, you will only receive data that is newer than your job start. Otherwise set auto.offset.reset to "earliest" 2) bootstrap.servers needs to exactly match the values advertised by kafka (see the kafka broker config). If a broker advertises its dns name and you try to connect via the ip address, you will receive not data but no error either

Comment: Have you added spark-streaming-kafka jar in your pom?

Comment: I previously worked on this integration.If you want any help just share your email

Comment: @ user4342532 Can you please upload code in github or something..

Answer (score 1):

I am able to print string which fetch from the kafka queue using direct kafka stream..

Here is my code,

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Currency;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import scala.Tuple2;

import kafka.serializer.StringDecoder;

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.*;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.*;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.HasOffsetRanges;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.OffsetRange;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.omg.CORBA.Current;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.Duration;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.Durations;

public final class KafkaConsumerDirectStream {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        try {
            SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("JavaKafkaWordCount11").setMaster("local[*]");
            sparkConf.set("spark.streaming.concurrentJobs", "30");

            // Create the context with 2 seconds batch size
            JavaStreamingContext jssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sparkConf, new Duration(200));

            Map<String, String> kafkaParams = new HashMap<>();
            kafkaParams.put("metadata.broker.list", "x.xx.xxx.xxx:9091");

            Set<String> topics = new HashSet();
            topics.add("PartWithTopic02Queue");

            JavaPairInputDStream<String, String> messages = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(jssc, String.class,
                    String.class, StringDecoder.class, StringDecoder.class, kafkaParams, topics);

            JavaDStream<String> lines = messages.map(new Function<Tuple2<String, String>, String>() {
                @Override
                public String call(Tuple2<String, String> tuple2) {
                    return tuple2._2();
                }
            });

            lines.foreachRDD(rdd -> {

                if (rdd.count() > 0) {
                    List<String> strArray = rdd.collect();

                    // Print string here
                }
            });

            jssc.start();
            jssc.awaitTermination();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Vimal Here is a [link](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/streaming/DirectKafkaWordCount.scala) to the working version of creating direct streams in Scala.

I believe after reviewing it in Scala, you must convert it easily.

Please make sure that you are turning off for reading the latest topics in Kafka. It might not pick any topic which was processed last time.

Comment: I commented "kafkaParams.put("auto.offset.reset", "latest");" and still not able to get the result

Comment: Scala code and Java code is totally different.. I didnt get any solution from given Scala